# error 'Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}' after updating MikTex

Tags: miktex-update

My main issue is as follows:
(i) The tex is totally working before I update MikTex packages.
(ii) After I update MikTex today, I got this error in my tex file.
(iii) I found there is a reminder in MikTex after check for updates. See the snapshot attached.
(iii) I am using TeXstudio.

[image]

The source text in .tex are as follows:

```
\documentclass[journal]{new-aiaa}
%\documentclass[journal]{new-aiaa} for journal papers
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{longtable,tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt} 

\title{Hello world}

\author{Hello World\footnote{{Hello World}}}
\affil{Hello World}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Hello World.
\end{abstract}

Hello World.

\end{document}
```

**Could anyone help me with this issue? Many thanks in advance.**

```
\ProvidesClass{new-aiaa}[2018/01/10, v1.2]

\newif\if@conf
\newif\if@journal
\DeclareOption{conf}{\@conftrue}
\DeclareOption{journal}{\@journaltrue}

\ExecuteOptions{}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[10pt]{article}

\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{microtype}
\RequirePackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\RequirePackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\setlist{labelindent=\parindent,leftmargin=*,nosep}
\setlist[enumerate]{label={\arabic*)}}

\RequirePackage[symbol*]{footmisc}

\RequirePackage{setspace}
\if@conf
\fi
\if@journal
  \doublespacing
\fi

\RequirePackage[style]{abstract}
\renewcommand{\abstitlestyle}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\bfseries\normalsize}
\setlength{\absleftindent}{0.5in}
\setlength{\absrightindent}{0.5in}


\RequirePackage[blocks]{authblk}
\renewcommand{\Authfont}{\normalsize\upshape}
\renewcommand{\Affilfont}{\normalsize\itshape}
\setlength{\affilsep}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\and{\\[\baselineskip]}
  \centering\singlespacing
  {\LARGE\bfseries\@title\par}
  \vskip2\baselineskip
  \@author\par
  \endgroup
  \vskip\baselineskip
  \if@journal
    \thispagestyle{empty}
  \fi
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}
}


\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\large\bfseries\singlespacing\centering}
  {\thesection.\space}{0pt}{#1}[]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0.5\baselineskip}{0pt}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalsize\bfseries\singlespacing}
  {\Alph{subsection}.\space}{0pt}{#1}[]
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{0.5\baselineskip}{0pt}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalsize\itshape\singlespacing}
  {\arabic{subsubsection}.\space}{0pt}{#1}[]
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0.5\baselineskip}{0pt}

\RequirePackage{lettrine}
\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0pt}

\RequirePackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}
\captionsetup*{font=bf,labelsep=quad}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\RequirePackage[indentfirst=false,font+=small,leftmargin=0.4in,rightmargin=0pt,vskip=0pt]
{quoting}

\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{\baselineskip}

\RequirePackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}
% \bibliographystyle{aiaa}
\bibliographystyle{new-aiaa}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\small}

\RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
```

Log file is too long to show complete. I include the error part:

```
Package chemgreek Info: Activating mapping `newtx' on line 19.


! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           Use \cs_prefix_spec:N not \token_get_prefix_spec:...
l.19 \begin{document}
                     
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           Use \cs_prefix_spec:N not \token_get_prefix_spec:...
l.19 \begin{document}
                     
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           Use \cs_prefix_spec:N not \token_get_prefix_spec:...
l.19 \begin{document}
                     
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           Use \cs_prefix_spec:N not \token_get_prefix_spec:...
l.19 \begin{document}
                     
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


(C:\Users\kk\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/siunitx.tds/tex/
latex/siunitx\siunitx-abbreviations.cfg
File: siunitx-abbreviations.cfg 2017/11/26 v2.7k siunitx: Abbreviated units
)
(C:\Users\kk\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/translator\trans
lator-basic-dictionary-English.dict
Dictionary: translator-basic-dictionary, Language: English 
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OT1+ntxtlf on input lin
e 19.
```

Sorry, the log data is too long to shown. Please see the full log from the download link of test.log:
[test.log](https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20210624T8q5kMaK)

I cannt find where to switch user mode and admin mode for my MikTex. Please see the snapshot of my MikTex:

[image]

Comment: where is the source of the class? Also show the complete log-file.

Comment: the tex error message tells you which command is undefined. It will not be `\begin{document}`  Unfortunately texstudio's "summary" of error messages is worse than useless and is totally misleading. You need to look in the log file for the actual error message,

Comment: Dear both, I have uploaded the content of the class and the log file. Could you help with the issue? Thanks a lot.

Comment: you are using a package using commands from an older version of expl3 updating miktex (in user and admin modes) should fix it

Comment: your document runs without error in an up to date texlive (sorry I don't have miktex to test but it should  be OK as well)

Comment: Sorry, the issue occurs after I update MikTex. I just attempted to run the file in Overleaf without this issue.

Comment: Please show the full log not just part of it. Also you need to update miktex in **both** miktex user mode **and** miktex admin mode (they place files in two different places and one takes precedence over the other and thus old versions may linger)

Comment: The full log is too long to directly present. Alternatively, I add a link to download the log file. I am not familiar with MikTex. i cannot find where to switch user mode or admin mode for my miktex. In the overview tab of my miktex, I cannot find 'operation mode'.